# GRUB wont load dual-boot Ubuntu after post-installation update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, mbr

I am new to Ubuntu. I have tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 along side with Windows 10.

I have an all-Windows drive (/dev/sda) and another drive (/dev/sdb) with an 8 GB swap partition on /dev/sdb1 and an ext4 root partition of 240 GB on /dev/sdb2.

Ubuntu installs, and sets up secure boot. I set Ubuntu UEFI as number 1 boot device afterwards (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU74c.jpg), and Ubuntu loads. I then ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. After it finished, I rebooted and it goes to the `grub>` prompt of GNU GRUB v2.02 .

I have tried reinstalling many times, placing bootloader both on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, but it does the same thing. If i run `ls` in grub, I can only see hd0

What am I doing wrong?

ADDITION: Here is my Boot-info report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sT6mkD6pkc/

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? Both systems should be in same boot mode. But since different drives, do not have to be, just you then cannot use grub to dual boot, only UEFI boot menu. And you may have to turn on/off UEFI settings to match install. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: oldfred's right. Also, `sudo apt update && apt upgrade` was a mistake; apt always requires sudo every time, and the correct command would have been `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @K7AAY, you are right, my mistake

Comment: @oldfred, her is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sT6mkD6pkc/

Comment: Also both Windows and Ubuntu should be installed with UEFI

Comment: Bit unusual configuration, but should work. Have you tried with UEFI Secure Boot off? And you need Windows fast start up off, if you want to dual boot from grub menu. Otherwise only from UEFI menu. It looks like you may have installed in BIOS/MBR mode, then re-instlaled or reconfigured for UEFI. Your sdb drive is MBR, where normally UEFI used gpt. And you have grub in MBR for BIOS boot, just do not ever boot in BIOS mode, and that grub will never be used. UEFI/gpt partitioning, now no partition: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Strange strange. I just tried to boot Ubuntu from USB and bam, grub showed my current installation, and Ubuntu booted fine. I remove USB and reboot, and grub still works, loading Ubuntu normal. I can't explain what did the trick, but it works now... Thanks for all the help